# ggplot: how to draw a plot with colored columns?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, colors, bar-chart

Hy guys, I'm need to replicate this kind of plot [Real Wages differences for each city](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wUKF.png)

In the x axis there is the code of each city, while in the y axis the values of the real wage.
Actually, I have 2 different variables for real wage ( `Real wage 1` and `Real Wage 2` ).
Real Wage 1 is always bigger than Real wage 2, hence the orange part of the bars should represent the percentage more compared with Real wage 1 ( blu part).

My database is something like this

```
#database
City Code   Real Wage 1    Real Wage 2
91          530            500
92          520            490
93          410            390
94          300            270
95          205            200
96          501            434
97          700            678
98          800            730   
99          900            820
100         740            700
101         590            560 
102         420            400
103         340            320
104         290            270   
105         120            100
```

How can I do that?
I don't even know if it is possible with ggplot2 overlap the bars of 2 variable or write the percentage in the orange part of each bar

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @Chamkrai for the code.
Does anyone have any idea how to write the % of difference within each bar as in the picture i've posted?

**UPDATE 2**
Thanks to @r2evans for the remaining part of the code

**UPDATE 3**
( I ve substitute the variable City Code with the variable `Provincia` which is a character variable, containing the name of each city ).

**UPDATE 4**
It works!!
I should have used select before mutate!!
THANKS TO ALL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-City_Code) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  aes(x = reorder(City_Code, value), y = value, fill = name) + 
  geom_col() + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! have you any idea how to put the % of difference whitin each bar?

Comment: how did you set the variables "value" and  "name" from my database??

Comment: To add "%", add `mutate(pct = scales::percent((Real_Wage_2 - Real_Wage_1) / Real_Wage_1))` before the pivot, and then add `+ geom_text(aes(label = pct), data = ~ subset(., name == "Real_Wage_1"))`, resulting in https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AC0L.png You can use `hjust=` to shift it left/right of the join-line. If you want to shift it to the far-right of each horiz bar, then perhaps post-pivot you can `group_by(City_Code) %>% mutate(pcty = sum(value))` and then `aes(label = pct, y = pcty)` for https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJPdP.png.

Comment: hi @r2evans thank another time for the answer. I think there is something missing in the code or in contrast with my datatset... i've edited the post so you can see what is the R answer

Comment: Right, pivot with `pivot_longer(-c(City_Code, pct))` instead

Comment: @r2evans it works! but i get all the 13 variables of my dataset in teh filling of the bars... How can i have only "Real Wage 1" and "Real Wage 2"?

Comment: You shouldn't be surprised by my answer to that question ... it isn't in your sample data, so I'm not entirely sure what you have and what you intend. Perhaps you need to `select(City_Code, starts_with("Real_Wage"))` early in the dplyr pipe (before pivoting)?

Comment: @r2evans you are right. I have this dataset with 14 variables and 106 obs. I need to make the plot with only the last 2, which I called here for simplicity "Real Wage 1" and "Real Wage 2" ( actually, their real names are "Real Wage" and "PPA Wage" )

Comment: Okay, so ... `select` just the ones you want to plot _before_ pivoting. Does that not resolve the issue?

Comment: @r2evans  is it the right way?    mutate(pct = scales::percent((`Salario Reale` - `PPA Salario`) / `Salario Reale`)) %>%
    select(`Salario Reale`,`PPA salario`) %>%
    pivot_longer(-c(`Provincia`, pct)) %>%

Comment: because R answers <<Error in `build_longer_spec()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `Provincia` doesn't exist.>>

Comment: The variable "Provincia" is a character variable .... To simplify i've called it the post "City Code". I'm going to update the post with the R answer

Comment: io_boh, I really don't know. The answer that Chamkrai provides resolves your first issue, my annexed code supports the second, both based on the sample data you provided. It is generally up to you to adapt the code based on your _sample_ data to your _real_ data.

Comment: @r2evans you are right. I've tried to do it...I've just uploaded my code in the original post... Is it the variable "Provincia" ( that contains name rather than number) that cause this problem??

Comment: I really don't know, io_boh. Perhaps add the output from `dput(head(df))` into your question.

Comment: @r2evans It works!! I should have used "select" before "mutate"!! THANKS

Comment: @r2evans i've just find out that the script is doing a different thing than the one i was looking for.... I added UPDATE 5 to explain the problem ... Can you help me?

Comment: No, I think I can't: there's too much confusion over Codes versus "Torino", changing column names, and non-specific "this is what I want" based on completely different data. io_boh, it's really difficult to understand what's going on when you keep switching between sample-data and real-data and real-data-filtered and such.

Comment: @r2evans I've studied the script you have provided me and i'm been able to do it by myself. Thank you very much for your time and for the help

Answer (score 0):

This expanded code is based on @Chamkrai's excellent first-answer, please accept that answer over this. I offer it here for concise clarity on the comments.

```r
df %>%
  mutate(pct = scales::percent((Real_Wage_2 - Real_Wage_1) / Real_Wage_1)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(City_Code, pct)) %>%
  group_by(City_Code) %>%
  mutate(pcty = sum(value)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = reorder(City_Code, value), y = value, fill = name) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(aes(label = pct, y = pcty), data = ~ subset(., name == "Real_Wage_1"), hjust = 1.1)
```

[image: ggplot barplot with colors and labels]